# How do I convert from an unmanaged C++ dll char** to a C# string and back

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am trying to call a function on a unmanaged C++ DLL, searching stackoverflow posts I came up close but I cant get it to fully work.

With a declaration in the .h file as follows:

```
extern int SomeDLLMethod(const char **data, int *count);
```

the data is a string

I have declared in C# as follows:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int SomeDLLMethod(IntPtr data, ref int count);
```

Then i can call it from C# as follows:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* buffer = new byte[MAX_LENGTH])
    {
        IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(buffer);
        int count = 0;
        var retVal = SomeDLLMethod(ptr, ref count);
        var dataString = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr);
        Console.WriteLine(dataString);
     }
 }
```

The call succeeds, there is a count and data in buffer, but how do I read this value back to C# string?

The Marshal methods is giving me garbage

Comment: Did you try passing in the count to Marshal.PtrToStringAuto?

Comment: const char ** suggests an array of null-terminated strings (pointer to array of pointers), not a single string. From what I see, you're trying to treat the parameter as a byte array, which seems to be the cause of unwanted results.

Comment: Is the method giving you garbage because the C# strings have 16 bit wide chars, while the C++ chars are 8 bits? In your question, the description of what SomeDLLMethod does is

Comment: @Spook more likely is that char** is a pointer to a C string rather than an array of C strings

Comment: @MrLister That's a very good point

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In this case it was, but it could be both, couldn't it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah, OK, as you can see I'm not too familiar with inter-language constructs like this. But I'm learning.

Comment: @MrLister no it was me that was in error. Your point was correct. PtrToStringAuto uses 8 bit on win 9x and 16 bit on NT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not enough information in the question to be 100% sure but my guess is that you need this:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int SomeDLLMethod(ref IntPtr data, ref int count);
.....
IntPtr data;
int count;
int retval = SomeDLLMethod(ref data, ref count);
string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(data, count);
```

Ideally when asking a question like this you should include the full documentation of the native function. I say this because a char** can mean many different things.

My assumption is that the char** here is a pointer to a null-terminated C string allocated by the DLL. Your code assumes that the caller allocates the buffer but if that were so then I would expect to see char* rather than char**.

Comment: As in my post i said the data is a string, according to the documentation. The documentation and library is proprietary so I didnt want to post specifics, however your solution works perfectly, the count argument is misleading here because the data is actually a csv string and the count is the number if items in the delimited string, so they dont match, I had to just use  Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr) which works.